# what to make out of it when Euler-Lagrange Equation is constantly zero

Tags: calculus-of-variations, vector-fields, euler-lagrange-equation

I'm new to Calculus of Variations, and I'm trying to apply it to a simple vector calculus problem.
Let's consider finding a curve $C$ along which the work $W$ done by a given vector field $\textbf{F}$ is maximized. Obviously $W$ can be expressed by

$$W = \int_C \textbf{F}\cdot d\textbf{r}$$

Since a line integral in essence is a single-variable integral, we can rewrite the above integral as

$$W = \int_C \textbf{F}\cdot d\textbf{r} = \int_C \textbf{F}(\textbf{r}(t))\cdot \textbf{r'}(t)dt=\int_C L(t,\textbf{r},\textbf{r'})dt$$

where $\textbf{r}(t)$ is the displacement

I used the one-dimensional Euler-Lagrange Equation,

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \textbf{r'}}) - \frac{\partial L}{\partial \bf{r}}=0$$
which actualy yields
$$\textbf{F'}(\textbf{r}) \cdot \textbf{r'} - \textbf{F'}(\textbf{r}) \cdot \textbf{r'} = 0$$

My question is :

1. Is there any mistakes in the steps?
2. what can we say about this constantly zero result? I noticed that the original derivation in 1-D Euler-Lagrange equation is to find the functional $y$ (in my case is $\textbf{r}(t)$) in terms of $t$ or $x$ that maximize a certain integral, and E-L equation is a necessary condition but not a sufficient for the extremal (similar to setting the derivative/gradient to zero). Does it mean this methods(E-L equation) fails in this case(we can't tell what curve maximize the line integral) or am I missing some underlying constraints here?
3. I've found a similar thread [When the Euler Lagrange equation simplifies to zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/112632). I'm not sure if I get this right but it seems the answer here implies a constantly zero E-L equation only tells us that the integral is of the same form regardless of the candidate function $\textbf{r}(t)$ here.
4. If we consider a special case, say, $C$ is a closed curve ($\textbf{r}(t)$ takes the same value at the both endpoints), then the original line integral (now turns into a contour integral) can be rewrite into a double integral of the curl using Stokes' theorem:

$$W = \oint_C \textbf{F}\cdot d\textbf{r} = \iint_D (\nabla \times \textbf{F}) \cdot d\textbf(A)$$

where $D$ is the region enclosed by the closed curve $C$, then clearly the extrema of the integral is also dependent on the vector field $\textbf{F}$, but how can I include this info in the E-L equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a mistake in your deviation.
First we note that $L = \sum_j F_j \dot r_j$
$$ \frac{\partial L}{ \partial r_i} = \sum_j \frac{\partial F_j}{ \partial r_i} \dot r_j$$

$$ \frac{\partial L}{ \partial \dot r_i} = F_i$$
$$\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{ \partial \dot r_i} = \sum_j \frac{\partial F_i}{ \partial r_j} \dot r_j$$

Hence the Euler lagrange equation reads

$$ \sum_j\left (\frac{\partial F_i}{ \partial r_j}  - \frac{\partial F_j}{ \partial r_i} \right) \dot r_j = 0$$

This it clearly trivial iff $\nabla \times F = 0.$ In this case the field in conservative and the integral constant if the endpoints are fixed.

The consistently $0$ result is what happens when your integral is constant. It is basically analogous to how constant functions have derivative $0$.

Comment: Ohh I see, so each component has to be treated separately. Thank you for your clarification! I also wanna confirm if it is safe to assume that $\frac{\partial F_i}{\partial r_j} - \frac{\partial F_j}{\partial r_i} = 0$ for all available $i,j$ here, because $\dot{r_i}$ are independent?

Comment: well might be another silly question, (I can't come up with another case for now), is Calculus of Variations mainly focusing on functions/maps from Field to Field rather than other more complexed functions/maps from sets to sets like vector spaces. or in other words, if Calculus of Variations have vector/tensor forms.

Comment: ohhh $\frac{\partial F_i}{\partial r_j} - \frac{\partial F_j}{\partial r_i}$ is actually a component of the curl of $\textbf{F}$, at least for the 2-D and 3-D cases

Comment: For the first question yes that's right. And for the second, calculus of variations can totally be done (and very often is) with vectors and tensors. Often it is easier to do things with components then leave everything in vector notation though.